# Access local database

Tags: .net, windows, sqlite, entity-framework-core, maui

Using Entity Framework Core to access an SQLite database is working on Windows as long as I set the data source to the full qualified path. I want to embed this database in my app. I've added database.db to the `Resources\Raw` folder and set the `BuildAction` to `MauiAsset`.

I added this to the `.csproj` file:

```
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\database.db" />
```

But the `"Data Source=database.db"` string doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not a MAUI expert but I don't think you can open a SQLite database from the assets. The connection string expects a file system path but as I understand the asset files can be opened only as streams using FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync. The best solution probably is to save the asset file to FileSystem.AppDataDirectory and open it from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must copy your database from the app package to the App data directory.

```
string databaseName = "database.db3";

string databasePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, databaseName);

Task<Stream> task = FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync($"Resources/Raw/{databaseName}");

var stream = task.Result;

using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

File.WriteAllBytes(databasePath , memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Then, etablish the connection to the database with the variable databasePath

It is also working for Android platform.